# Can you use spring-boot-starter-test without starter-web?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to write integration tests in a separate project that does not have "web" code just tests. I'm trying to only add spring-test-starter like this:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'
```

without having to also add this (or a similar starter)

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'
```

But it appears that when I go to use
[org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html#getForEntity-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-)

The return type is not included in org.springframework.boot.test it's under "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity"

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> getForEntity(String url,
                                          Class<T> responseType,
                                          Map<String,?> urlVariables)
                                   throws RestClientException
```

I can't find anywhere that says that spring-boot-starter-test depends on say spring-boot-starter-web because otherwise what would be the point of the starter? Is there a way to use TestRestTemplate without depending on (2) starters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the starter packages, then you need to add dependency for the packages you want manually. Like `ResponseEntity` is a part of `spring-web`. So you need to add `spring-web` dependency to you `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file.

if you only want spring-web for testing, then you can add this line to your build.gradle file.

```
testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.2.9.RELEASE'
```

or your pom.xml file

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Check the version you need.